# What tool can generate MD5 from the command-line?

Tags: windows-xp, automation, script, md5

Is there any tool that can automate by script to generate file MD5?

I used to use Cygwin but I am looking for another solution without having Cygwin installed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [hashutils](http://code.kliu.org/misc/hashutils/) package has an `md5sum.exe` utility.  It simply uses Microsoft's Crypto APIs and will leave you I/O bound, which isn't necessarily the case with other tools.  For example, I've benchmarked the `md5sum` from UnxUtils against this one and UnxUtils is significantly slower.  I bet CygWin would be even worse.  The author also wrote the excellent [HashCheck](http://code.kliu.org/hashcheck/), a shell extension for hash generation & verification.

Comment: +1 That hashutils thing is awesome. If you also put it in the classpath, it's even more awesome :D . Thanks.

Comment: @RaduMurzea Classpath?! That's Java not Windows. Were you born after java or something?! It's called a PATH

Comment: @barlop OK fine, my bad. I hadn't come across them in a while and forgot which is which :) .

Comment: PS: Given how old Java is, it's not that unreasonable to think that it's older than me :D .

Answer (score 4):

`md5sum` is included in the coreutils package of [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/).

GnuWin provides ports of tools with a GNU or similar open source license, to modern MS-Windows (Microsoft Windows 2000 / XP / 2003 / Vista / 2008 / 7)

Answer (score 4):

Check out [MS Support - Availability and description of the File Checksum Integrity Verifier utility](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/841290):

> The File Checksum Integrity Verifier (FCIV) is a command-prompt utility that computes and verifies cryptographic hash values of files. FCIV can compute MD5 or SHA-1 cryptographic hash values. These values can be displayed on the screen or saved in an XML file database for later use and verification.

Answer (score 2):

Use [MD5Sums](http://www.pc-tools.net/win32/md5sums/). See the options it has.

```
MD5sums 1.2 freeware for Win9x/ME/NT/2000/XP+
Copyright (C) 2001-2005 Jem Berkes - http://www.pc-tools.net/

Usage: md5sums.exe [OPTION] filespec1 [filespec2 ...]

OPTION switches:
-B  Base64 encoded output, instead of default hex format
-b  Bare output, no path headers
-e  Exit immediately; don't pause before returning
-n  No percent done indicator
-p  Pause before returning (incompatible with -e)
-s  Display statistics at end (hashing speed)
-u  Mimic output of UNIX md5 command (implies -b, -n)

Examples:
md5sums c:\temp
md5sums original.doc copy*.doc backup*.doc
md5sums -n -e d:\incoming > log
```

Answer (score 1):

### [ExactFile](http://www.exactfile.com)

> ExactFile is a file integrity verification tool:
>
> - Use it to make sure files copied to CD-ROM are bit-perfect copies,
> - Use it to make sure backups copied from one drive to another are just right,
> - Use it to make sure files haven’t been changed or damaged over time.
>
> Multi-threaded, so your extra CPU cores get used when scanning multiple files and work gets done faster.
>
> Happy with Unicode file names, so it doesn’t fail when you’re using it on files named in Japanese, Hebrew, Chinese, or any other language.
>
> Supports multiple checksum routines (hashes), like MD5, SHA1, CRC32, RIPEMD and others.
>
> Supports recursive directory scanning.
>
> Supports Very Big Files — If it’s on your hard drive, ExactFile can handle it.
>
> Does everything popular file summer utilities do, like fsum, md5sum, sha1sum, sfv, etc, but better!
>
> Compatible with popular file checksum digest formats.
>
> For Windows 2000, XP, Vista, and 7.
>
> GUI. Easy to use to get checksums for individual files, create checksum digests, and test checksum digests. Does not require the console version or any external DLLs.
>
> FREE.