# Hashutils to recurse the whole drive

Tags: windows-7, command-line, md5, md5sum

Following this post [another super user question](https://superuser.com/questions/140323/what-tool-can-generate-md5-from-the-command-line), I downloaded hashutils. Works great with with the -r flag to recurse a folder. However, I am unable to recurse a whole drive.

Trying this command, the program returns straight away, with no message:

> c:> md5sum.exe -r "F:\"

Using windows 7.

Am I entering the wrong arguments? Is there a way to specify them correctly without writing a script?

Any tips greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Am I entering the wrong arguments?

From the (minimal) documentation (readme.txt) the quotes `"` are not required for the filenames argument:

> The -r command line switch may be used to walk the directory tree; for
>   example, to get the MD5 hashes of the entire Windows directory tree,
>   run
>
> ```
> "md5sum -r C:\Windows".
> ```

You cannot use just a drive name as the filename argument.

Try the following command:

```
md5sum.exe -r F:\*
```

Example:

```
md5sum -r e:\*
44f15d5d40b008749fbd38b754cb4e58 *e:\Agent\00000001.IDX
e6415767b23268f2bf28da9b90bcab73 *e:\Agent\00000002.IDX
4370bafc009a65b3dc2e6c721e6b5da4 *e:\Agent\00000003.IDX
cc8a1bf949ef58c3effe5a65f97c8052 *e:\Agent\00000004.IDX
2d4ba87616ecbd0d815895dce274cf9c *e:\Agent\00000005.IDX

...
```

Comment: perfect. just what I needed